# Clone file upload input filed in form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, input, clone

I am making an upload form and I want users to add more input file fields to the form if they require using jquery if they want to upload more than one file. This is the code I have so far below that isn't working. You can also see this on js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benpaton/JUJxn/

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function () {
    $('#add-more-files').click(function() {
       var cloned = $(this).prev().clone();
       cloned.val(null);
       $(cloned).insertBefore($(this));
    });
});

<ul>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <li>Choose a file to upload:</li>
        <li><input name="uploadedfile" type="file" size="40" /></li>
        <li><a href="" id="add-more-files">Add file upload box</a></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></li>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not selecting the `<li>` element.
Also, your anchor needs a hash to prevent it from trying to resolve a url

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GppYE/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <li>Choose a file to upload:</li>
        <li><input name="uploadedfile" type="file" size="40" /></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="add-more-files">Add file upload box</a></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></li>
    </form>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
   //clone file upload box
   $('#add-more-files').click(function() {
      var cloned = $(this).parent().prev().clone();
      cloned.val(null);
      $(cloned).insertBefore($(this).parent());
   });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to select something that doesn't exist. `$('#add-more-files').prev()` will be an empty jQuery object. [`$.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selects the previous *sibling*, of which there are none given the selector you've supplied.

I believe you want something like `$(this).parent().prev().clone()`